# identifying when executor completes all tasks

Tags: asynchronous, dart, concurrency

I am trying to write a dart function, which will get players weight and in the end give you the average of all players weight.
I am using executor package to fetch 3 players weight in one go and then as soon as a player's weight is fetched, i add it to list.

Issue it that i can't add await before for loop, and without await the code after for loop gets executed. 
Is there anyway that i can sort of pause the program or return the value only when the executor tasks are complete?

```
avgWeight(int n)async {
    List playersWeight=[];
    Executor executor = Executor(concurrency: 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//      executor.join(withWaiting: true).;
      executor.scheduleTask(() async {
        int currentPlayerWeight = await PlayerDetail(i+1).fetchPlayerWeight();
        print('courrentPlayerNo: ${i+1} currentPlayerWeight : $currentPlayerWeight ');

        if(currentPlayerWeight!=null){
          await playersWeight.add(currentPlayerWeight);
        }

      });
     await  executor.join(withWaiting:true);
      print(playersWeight);//for debugging only. this shuld be printed only when all tasks are completed. 
    }
    //playersWeight.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / playersWeight.length
  }
```

Debug print statements of list of weights should be printed only after all tasks are completed. if value of n is 4 then list should be printed just once after all 4 elements are added, but for me its printing with each element.

current output

```
[200]
[200, 190]
[200, 190, 265]
[200, 190, 265, 255]
```

needed output:

```
[200, 190, 265, 255]
```

I need to return avg weight but i can't do that because of current issue.

Comment: Any reason for the join are inside the for loop? I does not seem to make much sense. If that is not the problem could you then made a small example which shows the problem and can be executed by others?

Comment: i feel stupid now. wasted way too much time on this. even my friends were not able to pick this mistake. thank you.
its working now after moving it outside for loop

Comment: No problem. I have added an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments the problem was that `await  executor.join(withWaiting:true);` was inside the for-loop but should have been outside.